# LinkedHashMap ordered by value

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap, linkedhashmap

I'm trying find a structure similar to a LinkedHashMap that sorts it by its value.
I'll need to be able to update the values.
I'll be checking the order very often, so I need a solution that avoids sorting the Map every time.

something like this:

```
DynamicSortedMap<String,Integer> map = new DynamicSortedMap<String,Integer>();
map.put("key1",4);
map.put("key2",3);
map.put("key3",6);
System.out.println("Map: "+map);
map.update("key1",1);
System.out.println("Update:"+map);
```

Output:

```
Map: {key3=6, key1=4, key2=3}
Update: {key3=6, key2=3, key1=1}
```

Is there any stucture that allows this?
If not, any ideas of how to do it?

Thanks for your help,

Comment: A `LinkedHashMap` is ordered by insertion not value. What you're looking for is [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html).

Comment: I echo the recommendation of TreeMap.  What features of LinkedHashMap made you pick it over other Maps?

Comment: `TreeMap` is sorted by key (but I think OP wants it like that). :)

Comment: Try to use `final SortedMap<String, String> st = new TreeMap<String,String>();`

Comment: I need to be sorted by value, and to be able to update the different elements (if there is not other solution, I may remove and re-insert the element with the new value)

Comment: What's the point of sorting map entries by value?

Comment: No, there isn't any structure which allows you to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like TreeMap, which is sorted by key:

```
SortedMap<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though LinkedHashMap in fact could be a good base for this it's unfortunately very limited in manipulating the iteration order. I think with [apache common-collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/) your better on.

Answer (score 0):

```
class SortValueMap extends HashMap<String,Integer>{

    @Override
    public Set<Entry<String,Integer>> entrySet() {
        List<Entry<String,Integer>> entries = new ArrayList<Entry<String,Integer>>(super.entrySet());
        Collections.sort(entries, new Comparator<Entry<String,Integer>>(){

            @Override
            public int compare(Map.Entry<String,Integer> o1, Map.Entry<String,Integer> o2) {
                return o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue());
            }});
        return new LinkedHashSet<Entry<String,Integer>>(entries);
    }
 }
    ...
SortValueMap  map = new SortValueMap();
map.put("key1",4);
map.put("key2",3);
map.put("key3",6);
map.put("key4",1);
System.out.println("Map: "+map);
```